# Select .change function not working in one instance but works in the other

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have created a WordPress theme and have a small dropdown box to sort a set of results, this is created using the following code;

```
<div id="search-results-container-sort">
<form id="listings-sort" action="" method="post">
    <label for="listing-results-sort">Sort by</label>
    <select name="sort" id="listing-results-sort-options">
        <?php $date_sort_defaults = array('select', 'newest', 'oldest', 'price highest', 'price lowest');
        foreach($date_sort_defaults as $default) {
            if( isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == $default ) {
                echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$_GET['sort'].'">'.ucfirst($_GET['sort']).'</option>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<option value="'.$default.'">'.ucfirst($default).'</option>';
            }
        } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

the form submit is triggered using;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('form#listings-sort select').change(function() {
        var input_name = $(this).prop('name');
        var input_val = $(this).val();
        $('form#search-form input[name="'+input_name+'"]').val(input_val);
        $('form#search-form').submit();
    } );

} );
```

When I try it on a local server it works fine, same if I upload it, but I have a user for whom the change simply doesn't fire. I have looked at his set-up and it's the same as mine with the only difference is that he is using GoDaddy hosting and I am using 1and1.

I can't understand why this will work in one instance and not the other, can anyone shed any light?

UPDATE: After realising I have a spare GoDaddy account I create a new WP install and then proceeded to install the theme. The change dropdown did not work, on inspecting the files it seems that installing the theme using GoDaddy added a blank line inbetween ever line of code on all files, breaking it.

Comment: DOM events firing (client-side) has nothing to do with hosting (server-side). What/where are `#search-form` and `#search-form input`? What about the reference to jQuery? Are you using CDN or local file? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @J.Titus jquery the same in both 1.11.3, local file, no errors in console. Search form is another form on the page that has the main search criteria, the sort form POSTS the sort values, thereby creating a new query including sort.

Comment: Uploading files to GoDaddy as binary files should solve the blank lines issue. Can you provide the links, seeing the source-codes would help.